# amCharts: Disable toggling of some items in Legend

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using a series' tooltip for showing all the series values of a chart in the same tooltip.

```
series1.tooltipText= '[bold]{dateX}[/]\\nSeries1Label: {series1}\\nSeries2Label: {series2}\\nSeries3Label: {series3}';
series2.tooltip.disabled = true;
series3.tooltip.disabled = true;
```

But I need a way to disable toggling for the series that has the tooltip, because disabling that series would make the tooltip disappear too.

As shown in amCharts documentation, you can [Disable toggling of items in Legend](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/disabling-toggling-of-items-in-legend/), but that is an option that applies to the whole chart:

```
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.clickable = false;
```

What if I need to disable it only for one series, while keep the toggling enabled for the other series? Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add hit event listener on the `legend container`.

**EDIT**: Added `hidden` event inside `hit` event. Now `Marketing` legend will always show even the legend below is clicked to toggle (switching off the event after `show` so events don't pile up), consider the following:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_dataviz);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "research": 501.9,
  "marketing": 250,
  "sales": 199
}
, {
  "country": "Republic",
  //"research": 301.9,
  "marketing": 222,
  "sales": 251
}
];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.title.text = "Local country offices";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;


var  valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "Expenditure (M)";

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueX = "research";
series.dataFields.categoryY = "country";
series.name = "Research";
series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.stacked = true;
series.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusTopLeft", cornerRadius1);
series.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusBottomLeft", cornerRadius1);
series.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusBottomRight", cornerRadius);
series.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusTopRight", cornerRadius);

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueX = "marketing";
series2.dataFields.categoryY = "country";
series2.name = "Marketing";
series2.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series2.stacked = true;
series2.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusTopLeft", cornerRadius1);
series2.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusBottomLeft", cornerRadius1);

series2.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusBottomRight", cornerRadius);
series2.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusTopRight", cornerRadius);

var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueX = "sales";
series3.dataFields.categoryY = "country";
series3.name = "Sales";
series3.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series3.stacked = true;
series3.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusTopLeft", cornerRadius1);
series3.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusBottomLeft", cornerRadius1);

series3.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusBottomRight", cornerRadius);
series3.columns.template.column.adapter.add("cornerRadiusTopRight", cornerRadius);

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

function cornerRadius(radius, item) {
 var dataItem = item.dataItem;
 // Find the last series in this stack
 var lastSeries;
 // console.log(chart.series)
 chart.series.each(function(series) {
  if (dataItem.dataContext[series.dataFields.valueX] && !series.isHidden && !series.isHiding) {
   lastSeries = series;
  }
 });
 // If current series is the one, use rounded corner
 dataItem.component == lastSeries ? 100 : radius;
 // console.log(dataItem)
 return dataItem.component == lastSeries ? 10 : radius;
}

function cornerRadius1(radius, item) {
 var dataItem = item.dataItem;
 var lastSeries;
  var flag = false;
 chart.series.each(function(series) {
  if (dataItem.dataContext[series.dataFields.valueX] && !series.isHidden && !series.isHiding && !flag) {
   lastSeries = series;
      flag = true;
  }
 });
   dataItem.component == lastSeries ? 100 : radius;
 return dataItem.component == lastSeries ? 10 : radius;
}
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    series2.events.on("hidden", function() {
        series2.show();
        series2.events.off("hidden");
    });
//console.log("Clicked on "+ ev.target.dataItem.name);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 9pt;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 401px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/dataviz.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @dolma33 does this answer your question?

Comment: Can you provide JSON for 
```chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {series2.events.on("hidden", function() {series2.show();series2.events.off("hidden");});
//console.log("Clicked on "+ ev.target.dataItem.name);});```

Comment: @KushalJ. I'm sorry I don't understand your question, can you please provide some details? Better yet you can ask a question with apt tags.

Comment: I have generated amcharts4 using JSON configs and you have a code with Object style. Just need a compatible code that would work with JSON config. I have the same requirement of disabling a first legend item. Something like this: ```"events": {
            "hit": function (ev) {
              var chart1 = ev.target.baseSprite;
              console.log('chart1::: ', chart1.series);
              console.log("Clicked on ", ev);
              // console.log("Clicked on ", ev);
            }
          }```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample? on jsfiddle for example

Comment: Hi @shrys - fortunately I found the solution and posted the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68804573/1841647