# Amcharts4 - How to disable toggling for first legend item

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I faced an issue while working on a `stockchart` or `XYChart` series, where I had to display multiple series. Now the requirement was making the very 1st legend item disabled for the toggling functionality.

Well, it was easy to do so when we take the object approach. However, the same becomes a little tricky with the JSON configuration approach. Unfortunately, I had to follow the JSON approach due to existing the migration code.

**An example can be found**: https://codepen.io/kutec/pen/yLbWyGJ

*Related question*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56587291/1841647

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to give the below solution that I used to fix my code.

```
legend: {
    'itemContainers': {
        'template': {
          'events': {
            'hit': function (ev) {
              let series = ev.target.baseSprite.series;
              if (ev.target.dataItem.index === 0) {
                series.show();
                series.events.off('hidden');
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Working [codepen](https://codepen.io/kutec/pen/dyWEoOa).

Hopefully, this would be helpful.

Thanks.